# Laravel 5.8 Authentication coming back to login page after signing in

Tags: php, laravel

After clicking the sign in button, page refreshes and comes back to the login page. I tried debugging with `dd()` but the data seems to be posting. I have included my blade, web.php and controller below.

login.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.login') }}" method="post">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div>        </div>
      </form>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

Controller

```
public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your named route is a get route which shows the login form and you are trying to submit the form to the get route, which just returns the same page with the login form.

In route definitions you can have the post route as the named one

```php
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('admin.login');
```

Comment: I am still redirected to the signup page.

Comment: These routes still appear more likely... while it is unknown what `LoginController` does.

Answer (score 0):

You change your default login system, so conflict url, change url -

```
Route::get('/admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

I hope it will be work!

Comment: I tried this and also tried taking it out of the group route and used `Admin\Auth\LoginController` but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is something different if the problem is not solved with the answers above.
Have you tried to look redirection operations at auth middleware?

Like this:

```
 protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```